# Asynchronous problem when calling fetch function for each element in array in js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this js code:

```
_fetchData = (id, callback) => {
      let url = 'https://.../id=' + id
      fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => callback(data))
}

_addToArray = (array) => {
      let dataArray = []
      array.forEach(item => {
           _fetchData(item.id, (data) => {
                 dataArray.push(data)
           })
      }
      return dataArray
}
```

I want `dataArray = [data1, data2, ...]`

but it's `dataArray = []`

What' re solutions for this? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can write `.then(data => callback(data))` as `.then(callback)`

Comment: @RoboRobok also possible to *not* pass it as a callback but return the promise and it directly to the promise chain. No need to convert a promise back to a callback solution. Promises are the *replacement* of callbacks.

Comment: @VLAZ also true!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using asynchronous code, since `fetch:

```js
_fetchData = (id) => {
    return fetch(`https://.../id=${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
}

_addToArray = (array) => {
    return Promise.all(array.map(item => _fetchData(item.id)));
}
```

or simply:

```js
_addToArray = (array) => {
    return Promise.all(array.map(item => 
        fetch(`https://.../id=${item.id}`).then(r => r.json())));
}
```